# error when trying to restore a dump file into a mysql docker image

Tags: mysql, docker

[cross post](https://forums.docker.com/t/restoring-a-dump-file-no-longer-works-change-in-command/99127)

Hi, it’s weird because it always worked for me and now I keep getting an error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insec’ at line 1

and I am copy and pasting the command that is in the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql):

```
$ docker exec -i some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"' < /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql
```

I then edit it to:

```
$ docker exec -i sql-db sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"super_secret_pw" users' < ./source.sql
```

also: after `$ docker ps` I get:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
8fa9cb82332e        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   sql-db
```

and I get the above error. thanks for any help

Comment: Mysqldump is executable file, means you can run on it command line and it is not mysql comand but i assume that you tried to run the mysqldump on mysql shell

Comment: yes I have tried that. But I think it is even more confusing that the docker command isn't working as it used to and can't see any update changes that would alter anything.

Comment: Don't know if that breaks and causes the error but after your password you have an additional "users".

Comment: @Ludo21South the `users` is specifying the database that the dump is going to

Comment: Are you able to connect to the instance directly (i.e. exe -it /bin/bash)? If so you could emulate the commands and see what is wrong.

Comment: wow so.... the problem was that `WITHIN` the dump itself it has that error!!!!

Answer (score 2):

So the issue was that at the top of the dump the text on line one is:

```
1   mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

Comment: Please read it https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/132